# Why does my variable return None instead of the stock price?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I tried to scrape the stock price from https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA/ using BeautifulSoup, but for some reason my program doesn't print the stock price and instead returns "None". How do I correctly scrape the stock price?
My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
headers = {"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36"}
url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA/"
time.sleep(10)
GetUrl = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(GetUrl.text)
StockPrice = soup.find({"Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)"})
print(StockPrice)
```

Here is the place that I found the data, which I copied to soup.find().[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `soup.find()`, use the `class_=` parameter:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA/"

GetUrl = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(GetUrl.text, "html.parser")

# use class_="..."
StockPrice = soup.find(class_="Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)")

print(StockPrice.text)
```

Prints:

```
975.93
```